# Smooth morphism to homogeneous spaces and fibers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a smooth morphism between projective varieties. Suppose $Y$ is a homogeneous space. Under what additional condition on $f$, can we conclude that every fibers of $f$ are isomorphic?

Comment: how's $Z$ related to the situation?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Corrected now.

Comment: This question is similar to others that come up from time-to-time, and I will remind of the following (sorry to keep repeating this): Moret-Bailly constructed pencils of Abelian surfaces over $\mathbb{P}^1$ that are not isotrivial.

Comment: Also, there is another example: starting with $X' = Y\times Z$ and with $N$ everywhere disjoint graphs of morphisms from $Y$ to $Z$, let $X$ be the blowing up of these graphs.  Because of these examples, usually people ask for the weaker conclusion that the fibers are birational.  Moret-Bailly's pencils are counterexamples to "birational triviality".

Comment: @Starr: Thank you very much for your answer. I am reading one of your articles "Families of rationally simply connected varieties over surface and torsors for semi-simple groups". In the first line of the proof of Lemma 15.7 you say that the considered evaluation map has isomorphic fibers because the target is homogeneous. I was trying to understand this statement.

Comment: I usually use "$f$ is equivariant".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular case, there is a sufficient hypothesis that the morphism is étale locally a product.  Let $k$ be a field.  Let $G$ be a smooth $k$-group scheme.  Let $$\Psi_X:G\times_{\text{Spec}(k)} X \to X\times_{\text{Spec}(k)} X, \ \ \Psi_X(g,x) = (g\cdot x,x), $$
$$\Psi_Y:G\times_{\text{Spec}(k)} Y \to Y\times_{\text{Spec}(k)} Y, \ \ \Psi_Y(g,y) = (g\cdot y,y)$$
be $k$-actions of $G$ on $X$, resp. $Y$.  Assume that $f$ is $G$-equivariant, $f(g\cdot x) = g\cdot f(x)$.  Finally, assume that the action $\Psi_Y$ is smooth and surjective, i.e., $Y$ is a $G$-homogeneous space whose stabilizer subgroup schemes are $k$-smooth.  Then the morphism $f$ is étale locally a product.

It suffices to prove this after étale base change, thus assume that $Y$ has a $k$-point $y$.  Then $\Psi_Y$ induces a smooth $k$-morphism, $$\psi_{Y,y}:G\to Y,\ \ \psi_{Y,y}(g) = g\cdot y.$$  Denote $X\times_{f,Y,y} \text{Spec}(k)$ by $X_y$.  Then there is a commutative diagram.
$$ \begin{array}{ccc}
G\times_{\text{Spec}(k)} X_y & \xrightarrow{\text{pr}_1\circ \Psi_X} & Y \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \downarrow{\text{pr}_G} & & \downarrow{f} \\
G & \xrightarrow{\psi_{Y,y}} & X
\end{array}$$
It is not too hard to check that this is actually a Cartesian diagram.  Thus, after the smooth base change $\psi_{Y,y}$, the morphism $f$ becomes a product.  Of course there are étale local sections of $\psi_{Y,y}$.  Thus, after étale base change of $Y$, the morphism $f$ becomes a product.